# dashboard.setCount, notifications.sendEmail works only with logged in user

Tags: facebook, api, sdk

I have an awkward problem:

I try to send emails(user haver permissions) and set counters(dashboard.setCount) but it works only for the user, who actually loget in. The other user couse errors, for example:

dashboard.setCount Error: 240, Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.

But it works, if I try the same without to be loged in in to facebook.

```
$param  =   array('method'  => 'dashboard.setCount','uid' => 'some_user_id', 'count' => 1);
$stat = $facebook->api($param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an access_token given by:

```
public static function get_dashboard_access_token()
{
  return self::$appId.'|'.self::$secret;
}
```

it works for me :)

Luca

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to use it!

Comment: well just concat $appId and $secret using "|" and use that as access_token. It's not difficult =)